# Compare difference between two dates using JPA Criteria Query

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api, datediff

I am using MySQL as a backend for my application.

I want to execute query below using JPA Criteria Query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE datediff(now(), t1.created) >= 20;
```

Note: Type of `created` is `TIMESTAMP`

I want Criteria Query like:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();

// select
CriteriaQuery<Table1> query = cb.createQuery(Table1.class);

// from
Root<Table1> root = query.from(Table1.class);

// where
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

// TODO: add expression for datediff(now(), t1.created) >= 20

query.where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
```

Can any one help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing that `created` is a `java.util.Date`, you have to perform the `DATEDIFF` in java and compare the property with the resulting date:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -20);
Date myDate = c.getTime();

predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get("created"), myDate));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But, there small mistake you made. I think it should not be **cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo()** it should be **cb.lessThanOrEqualTo()**. Because we are finding records older than _20 days_.