# EJB as an Interface is not injected

Tags: dependency-injection, ejb

I defined an interface.

```java
@Local
public interface MessageService {
}
```

And an implementation.

```java
@Stateless
public class MessageServiceSome implements MessageService {
}
```

When I tried to inject it into my resource class, I got `null`.

```java
//@Path("/messages") // I'M NOT GOING TO MAKE THIS STATELESS!!!
public class MessagesResource {

    // none of follwoing options works
    // leaves the field null
    @Inject
    //@EJB
    //@EJB(beanName = "MessageServiceSome")
    private MessageService messageService;
}
```

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE**

I think I have to admit that my question is not good enough.

The `MessagesResource` class was actually a sub resource. I didn't know the difference.

There are two very good threads for this issue.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36291890/330457
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24670218/330457

One is using [ResourceContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceContext.html) and the other is using [Inject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Inject.html).

Both threads are saying they work but I only succeeded with `@Inject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With little information provided, you have probably two quick options you can try:

1. leave @Inject only, if your project/container is CDI enabled

   @Inject
   private MessageService messageService;
2. leave @EJB only, do you really need the beanName ?

   @EJB
   private MessageService messageService;

on of the two should solve the issue.

**[UPDATE]**
Otherwise have a look at the app server start up log, and see if the bean has been deployed.